# how to prevent woocommerce saving user untill they pay?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce subscription. It is saving user and makes them logged on once they finish checkout form. How to make like they do not get saved / logged-in until payment success?

Comment: Is there anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hook into the woocommerce_thankyou hook and logout the current user there. But that is a little late. Better would be the user to be logget out before the page is displayed, not after.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_custom_logout_function_here', 10 );
function my_custom_logout_function_here( $orderid ) {
    echo 'Your message here';
    wp_logout();
}
```